# Quantile Regression with Quantiles based on independent variable

Tags: stata, sample, quantile

I am attempting to run a quantile regression on monthly observations (of mutual fund characteristics). What I would like to do is distribute my observations in quintiles for each month (my dataset comprises 99 months). I want to base the quintiles on a variable (lagged fund size i.e. Total Net Assets) that will be later employed as an independent variable to explain fund performance.

What I already tried to do is use the `qreg` command, but that uses quantiles based on the dependent variable not the independent variable that is needed.

Moreover I tried to use the `xtile` command to create the quintiles; however, the `by:` command is not supported.

```
    . by Date: xtile QLagTNA= LagTNA, nq(5)
    xtile may not be combined with by
    r(190);
```

Is there a (combination of) command(s) which saves me from creating quintiles manually on a month-by-month basis?

Comment: What you call functions are all commands to Stata. I've edited accordingly. Stata does have functions, but they are disjoint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Statistical comments first before getting to your question, which has two Stata answers at least.

1. Quantile regression is defined by prediction of quantiles of the response (what you call the dependent variable). You may or may not want to do that, but using quantile-based groups for predictors does not itself make a regression a quantile regression.
2. Quantiles (here quintiles) are values that divide a variable into bands of defined frequency. Here you want the 0, 20, 40, 60, 80, 100% points. The bands, intervals or groups themselves are not best called quantiles, although many statistically-minded people would know what you mean.
3. What you propose seems common in economics and business, but it is still degrading the information in the data.

All that said, you could always write a loop using `forval`, something like this

```
egen group = group(Date) 
su group, meanonly 
gen QLagTNA = . 

quietly forval d = 1/`r(max)' { 
      xtile work = LagTNA if group == `d', nq(5)  
      replace QLagTNA = work if group == `d' 
      drop work 
}
```

For more, [see this link](http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/try-all-values-with-foreach/)

But you will probably prefer to download a user-written `egen` function [correct term here] to do this

```
ssc inst egenmore 
h egenmore
```

The function you want is `xtile()`.